# Marcus Number Fields Chapter 4 Exercise 8

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Let $r,e,f$ be given positive numbers. I should try to demonstrate that there are always $p,q$ prime such that $p$ splits exactly in $r$ different prime in the $q$th cyclotomic field.

I know that there are infinite $q$ such that $q-1$ is divisible by $r$, so I was trying to take such a prime and look for a correct value of $p$. I came into the problem of demonstrating that there is always a prime $p$ with order $(q-1)/r$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(q)^*$, wh9ich does not seem trivial to me.

Comment: Try Dirichlet’s theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

Comment: Is there a way without using it?

Comment: How do you know that there are infinite $q$ such that $q-1$ is divisible by $r$? Isn't it because of Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: That's a version of Dirichlet Theorem you can prove with basic algebraic number theory. (The one about being equivalent to 1 mod q). While the general version not.

Comment: Then, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Comment: Marcus has an alternative approach to proving the existence of infinite $q$ such that $q \equiv 1\ (n)$ in Chapter 3 Exercise 30.  First you show that every polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a root for infinitely many primes, then you apply that to $x^n - 1 \equiv 0 \ (p)$; if $a^n \equiv 1 \ (p)$ then $n - 1 \mid p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this from the unanswered queue.

- Let $q$ be a prime congruent to $1$ modulo $r$. Those exist by virtue of Dirichlet's theorem of primes in an arithmetic progression.
- Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $q$. Let $a$ be the remainder of $g^r$ modulo $q$.
- Let $p$ be a prime congruent to $a$ modulo $q$. Such a prime exists again by Dirichlet.
- Because $p$ is of order $(q-1)/r$ we know that modulo $p$ the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_q(x)$ splits into exactly $r$ distinct irreducible factors, all of degree $(q-1)/r$. By basic algebraic number theory this means that the prime $p$ splits into a product of $r$ distinct prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_q]$.

Comment: The need to invoke Dirichlet is very annoying. If we needed to find a prime of order $r$ we could more or less pick a prime $p$ and let $q$ be a prime factor of $\Phi_r(p)$. Alas, that does not work here :-(