# Exercise 4.8 from Marcus'book "Number fields"

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, cyclotomic-fields

I report here the Exercise with my sketch of a solution.
[image]

(a) By Exercise 30 Chapter 3, I know that there are infinitely many primes $q \equiv 1 \bmod r$. Moreover, I know that the ring of integers of $K$ is $S=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_q]$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}[\zeta_q]$. Using Dedekind's Theorem (Theorem 27 in Chapter 3) I know that, if the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_q(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is factored into $r$ irreducible monic polynomials, then also $p$ does in the ring of integers $S$. By properties of cyclotomic polynomials, it's enough taking $p$ such that $p^{(q-1)/r} \equiv 1 \bmod q$ (of course there are infinitely many of such $p$'s).

(b) If $p^{(q-1)/r} \equiv 1 \bmod q$ with $r \neq 1$, then $\Phi_q(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p$ splits into $r$ monic irreducible polynomials of degree $(q-1)/r$. Using again Theorem 27, we know that the inertial degree is $f(Q_i|p) = (q-1)/r$ where $Q_i$ are those prime ideals arising from the factorization of $\Phi_q(x)$. Then, it's enough picking $q \equiv 1 \bmod rf$ to satisfy this point.

(c) There are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod e$. Then? I'm stuck

(d) No ideas

(e) I think $p=5$ and $q=31$ could work ($p^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 31$ and $p \equiv 1 \bmod 2$, moreover $q \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ and $q \equiv 1 \bmod 15$).

What do you think about the first two points and the latter one? Do they work?

Can you give me some hints for point (c) and (d) please?

( [Here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf),  Theorem 1 is Theorem 27 in Marcus'book, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208316/marcus-number-fields-chapter-4-exercise-8) there is a similar solution for point (a))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(c) In the first point you can choose q s.t is equal to *1 module ref*.
Then, when you choose p you know that is equal to *a module q*, as you can see here ([Marcus Number Fields Chapter 4 Exercise 8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208316/)), and that p is equal to *1 module e*.
So you have two different conditions on p, one about his residue module q and one about his residue module e.
Since e and q are coprime this two conditions are just one condition module e*q thanks to the Chinese Reminder Theorem.
Such a prime p exists thanks to Dirichlet's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I answer because I can't comment.
Let me just ask a question: $p$ never ramifies in the $q$-th cyclotomic field because it does not divide the discriminant if $q \neq p$. So at least in the first 4 point, shouldn't $e$ be always $1$?

Comment: Also, by theorem 26 of Marcus, $\varphi(p^k) = e$ but here $k = 0$

Comment: So maybe there is some mistake in the text of the exercise or i'm forgetting about something?

Comment: In the $q$-th cyclotomic field $e$ is always 1 but the question is about a subfield in the $pq$-th cyclotomic field.

Comment: For your “answer”: you were right,  however remember that “e” here is a number, a priori it is not the ramification index of “p”

Comment: For your comment: in the $qp$-cyclotomic field, $k=1$. In the $q$-cyclotomic field the Th 26 does not apply for $p$ but for $q$. Again $k=1$.